# GUIminer, unnable to connect to pool

Tags: miner-configuration, error, connection, guiminer, slush

I'm getting a connection error, or just a "connecting..." message that doesn't stop. though the connection on my end seems to be fine. This is a printout of my console. If there is already a fix for this, would someone please direct me to it? This is a screenshot of my console. I'm connecting to slush's pool if that helps.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GetfL.png

Comment: Apparently the URL of your pool was not entered properly, can you show us the configuration of your worker?

Answer (score -1):

use the GUIMiner-scrypt instead .... I could not get the guiminer to work.